# SQL, show a commom field

Tags: sql

New to SQL and working on a project. 
Imagine I want to show all the users which properties have been inspected by only one inspector.

I'm doing this but it show every user :-

```
select name, id, address
from user natural join inspector natural join inspects
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. In order for us to provide the best answer possible, you should include more information on your tables and data. Please provide the structure of the tables involved in your query, some sample data from each table, and what you want your result set to look like. And when you get a chance, take a look at the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, though it shouldn't matter too much for this question, you should tag your question with the appropriate DBMS flavor that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (exact syntax will depend on your tables):

```
SELECT name, id, address
FROM user natural join inspector natural join inspects
GROUP BY name, id, address
HAVING count(distinct inspector_id) = 1
```

Here you will want to replace inspector_id by some identifying attribute of inspector.